# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function in Laravel 5

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar, laravel-5

I'm trying to display the full calendar on my Laravel project but it seems my scripts aren't loading correctly.

I currently have everything hardcoded:

```
@extends('masterpage')
<link rel='stylesheet' href='{{ asset('/css/fullcalendar.css') }}' />
<script src='{{ asset('/js/jquery.min.js') }}'></script>
<script src='{{ asset('/js/moment.min.js') }}'></script>
<script src='{{ asset('/js/fullcalendar.js') }}'></script>
<style>

    body {
        margin: 40px 10px;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    #calendar {
        max-width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

</style>

@section('content')
<h1> Calendar </h1>
<div id='calendar'></div>
@stop

@section('footer')
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '2015-02-12',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: '2015-02-01'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: '2015-02-07',
                    end: '2015-02-10'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2015-02-09T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2015-02-16T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Conference',
                    start: '2015-02-11',
                    end: '2015-02-13'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2015-02-12T10:30:00',
                    end: '2015-02-12T12:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Lunch',
                    start: '2015-02-12T12:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2015-02-12T14:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Happy Hour',
                    start: '2015-02-12T17:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Dinner',
                    start: '2015-02-12T20:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: '2015-02-13T07:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    url: 'http://google.com/',
                    start: '2015-02-28'
                }
            ]
        });

    });

</script>
@stop
```

My js and css are located in my public folder and therefor I'm using the short tag to link them.

Anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Open the source file after PHP parsing in the browser and check if your JS file path is correct. With the developer tools in your browser, you'll see immediatly if it is loaded or not.

Comment: Yes, everything is loaded correctly: http://i.gyazo.com/7b78c81666c2a5e1ebb9f624ff23fc97.png

Comment: Then your scripts are loading... Think we need to see the page itself for this (so your view, or the rendered version). Also this clears out that it is not Laravel nor PHP related, but we need to look at the javascript.

Comment: That's just the thing. I downloaded the example from http://fullcalendar.io/download/ for testing and simply copied the basic view to see if everything works. The html pages from the zip load everything correctly so this should work..

Comment: Ok, so I tried editting the whole php file by simply copy-pasting the code given on the html and it show. The moment I extend the masterpage to make the document layout it fails and gives this error. Any Idea why it's doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I figured it out!
Seems like I was also pulling in a second jquery script on my master page
For anyone who ever has this problem, just make sure you're not doing any double code cause that will mess it up too!